# How to insert an entry to the store Dexie

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I keep getting this when trying to insert an entry to the store.

The schema was extended without specifying the version.
schemaError: KeyPath imgName on object store imageList is not indexed

Answer (score 0):

Just change the version number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).